# Python file works in VSCode but automatically crashes when run as an executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

Beginner here

I'm working on a program that can calculate the cumulative error between the estimated time it takes for a 3D printer to print (via Cura Slicer) and the actual time. I want to run the program as an executable using pyinstaller, but the command prompt the executable opens automatically closes. I was able to run the executable and close the window by using `input("Press any key to stop the program: ")`, but after I implemented `try: error_list=[]...except ZeroDivisionError: print("Sorry, there's nothing in this file").` the terminal window closes the moment it runs. Keep in mind, I tested the code in VSCode, and the `input()` works as expected, but in the terminal as an executable it automatically closes.

Why would a program work fine in VSCode, but automatically close when run as an executable? Any help is greatly appreciated!

To install the executable in cmd I use `pyinstaller .\CuraTimeError.py`

```
    def getError():
        f=open("errors.txt","r")
        data=f.read()
        try:  
            error_list=[]
            interations=iter(data)
            for char in range(len(data)):
                try:
                    thing=next(interations)
                except(StopIteration):
                    continue
                if thing == "*":
                    error=float(next(interations)+next(interations)+next(interations)+next(interations))
                    error_list.append(error)
            print("The current total error is: " +str(sum(error_list)/len(error_list)))
            f.close()
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Sorry, there's nothing in this file")

    getError()
    numberOfCases=int(input("How many tests are you inputting? "))
    if numberOfCases != 0:
        print("NOTE: Time follows 24-hour notation")
        for i in range(numberOfCases):
            print("Please enter case number "+str(i+1))
            f=open("errors.txt","a")
            curaTime=input("Cura estimated time: ")
            startTime=input("Start time: ")
            endTime=input("End time: ")
            if int(endTime)<int(startTime):
                endTime = str(int(endTime)+2400)
            actualTime=60*(int(endTime[0:2])-int(startTime[0:2]))+(int(endTime[2:4])-int(startTime[2:4]))
            estimatedTime= 60*(int(curaTime[0:2]))+int(curaTime[2:4])
                    error=(actualTime-estimatedTime)/(estimatedTime)+1
                    f.write(curaTime+","+startTime+","+endTime+",*"+str(round(error,2))+"\n")
                    f.close()
    getError()
    input("Press any key to stop the program: ")
```

Comment: run code in console/terminall manually and it will not close it on error - and you will see full error mesage.

Comment: python was created to run it on computer with preinstalled Python, not to run as .exe files - so tools like `pyinstaller` has sometimes problem to get all needed modules to run it correctly - it may have problem to recognize C/C++ modules needed by Python. It may have also run code in different folder then you expect (use `os.get_cwd()` to see Current Working Directory) and it may not find all files with data. You may have to use full path to files or you have to find in Google how to find folder with code and use it to create full path to data files.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a direct solution to this problem, so the workaround was to remove the need for the `try...except ZeroDivisionError` under the function `getError()` by adding a line of known data in the `errors.txt` file. This way the executable doesn't crash when attempting this try-except.